# Getting ConnectionError when using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip in debian chroot. I copied the /etc/resolv.conf from host to chroot. I can ping www.google.com and other websites.

When I run pip search pyopenssl in the chroot, I get following error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 122, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 424, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(0, 'Error')))
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(0, 'Error'))': /pypi
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
```

Comment: Are you able to curl to the URL ?

Comment: I can ping pypi.python.org. Running curl -X GET pypi.python.org/pypi, or curl -X GET curl -X GET pypi.python.org returns nothing

Comment: curl -L -X GET https://pypi.python.org with https follows redirect and gets the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that /proc and /dev directories were not mounted from the host to the chroot. Once mounted, pip works. Quite surprising.